# JSON parsing guidance using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have json data that looks like this

```
{
   "students":[{"id":"001", "name":"James"},{"id":"002", "name":"Sam"}]
   "courses":[{"id":"001", "name":"English"}, {"id":"002", "name":"Maths"}]
   "activity_feed":[{"template":"{students:001} registered for {courses:002}"},{"template":"{students:002} dropped {courses:001}"}]
}
```

What I am trying to do is use the json data to create an activity feed using javascript that will make use of the template field in activity_feed:

James registered for English

Sam dropped Mathematics

What is the best way to substitute the {students} and {courses} field in template with the respective names of the students and the courses?

Comment: What already you try so far? SO is help people to solve the problem not ask for free code

Comment: Honestly I am kinda new at this, if this was python, I would have used regex. I am looking for a way to extract the fields from the template

Comment: what you need is create looping based on your activity_feed. and why template format not like `James registered for English`? why using `{students:001}` ?

Comment: the assignment format looks like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by making your data easier to discover. For example, make your `students` and `courses` indexed by `id`.

All that's left after that is to iterate your activity templates and use a [regex callback to replace the tokens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```js
const data = {
   "students":[{"id":"001", "name":"James"},{"id":"002", "name":"Sam"}],
   "courses":[{"id":"001", "name":"English"}, {"id":"002", "name":"Maths"}],
   "activity_feed":[{"template":"{students:001} registered for {courses:002}"},{"template":"{students:002} dropped {courses:001}"}]
}

// a simple reducer function to map "name" properties to "id" in a Map
const indexById = (map, { id, name }) => map.set(id, name)

// create an object hash of these maps
const models = {
  students: data.students.reduce(indexById, new Map()),
  courses: data.courses.reduce(indexById, new Map())
}

const feed = document.getElementById('feed')
data.activity_feed.forEach(({ template }) => {
  let listItem = document.createElement('li')
  listItem.textContent = template.replace(/\{(\w+):(\w+)\}/g,
      (_, model, id) => models[model].get(id))
  feed.appendChild(listItem)
})
```

```html
<ul id="feed"></ul>
```